# How do I get a new pilot?

Tags: into-the-breach

I did miscalculate slightly in the last battle, and one of my mech pilots did die. I got a new mech for the next battle, but no pilot. Is there any way to get a new pilot during the campaign, or do I have to wait until it is finished to start with a fresh squad and new pilots?

[image: Mech without a pilot]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Pilots can be sometimes found in Time Pods if they're successfully secured during a mission, or they can be selected as a Perfect Island reward after completing all of an island's optional objectives.